# setDisable() inside DatePicker's setDayCellFactory not working if HijrahChronology is set

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8, javafx-datepicker

I am trying to use JavaFX 8's DatePicker with disabling the days that are not in the range [today, today + 1 year], similar to [the example in the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#CCHEBIFF). Here is the code:

**sample.fxml:**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">

    <DatePicker fx:id="dpDate"/>

</GridPane>
```

**Main.java:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    private final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @FXML private DatePicker dpDate;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = dp -> new DateCell()
        {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if(item.isBefore(LocalDate.now()) || item.isAfter(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)))
                {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb; -fx-text-fill: darkgray;");
                    setDisable(true);
                }
            }
        };

        StringConverter converter = new StringConverter<LocalDate>()
        {
            @Override
            public String toString(LocalDate date)
            {
                if(date != null) return dateFormatter.format(date);
                else return "";
            }

            @Override
            public LocalDate fromString(String string)
            {
                if(string != null && !string.isEmpty())
                {
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormatter);

                    if(date.isBefore(LocalDate.now()) || date.isAfter(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)))
                    {
                        return dpDate.getValue();
                    }
                    else return date;
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        dpDate.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
        dpDate.setConverter(converter);
        dpDate.setPromptText("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dpDate.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        dpDate.setChronology(HijrahChronology.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

This example works (i.e. user cannot select out of the range) only if I remove the last line `dpDate.setChronology(HijrahChronology.INSTANCE);` and leave it with default `IsoChronology`.

[image]

---

I have tried to consume the click event inside `updateItem()`:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
{
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if(item.isBefore(LocalDate.now()) || item.isAfter(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)))
    {
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb; -fx-text-fill: darkgray;");
        setDisable(true);

        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> e.consume());
    }
}
```

It works on the current month (the days before today cannot be selected). But if I go to the next months, it prevents the user from selecting a day from the permitted range.

---

Definitely this is a bug. Is there a workaround? How can I access the date picker popup? Maybe I can attach a listener to the button that change the month page, and then iterate over all the say cells and disable the out-of-range days manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a bug report in [JavaFX JIRA](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40237), and they will fix it the next update 8u60. Here is a workaround as suggested by Leif Samuelsson:

> > This is a bug in com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerHijrahContent. It overrides updateDayCells() and calls setDisable(false) on all cells after super has called updateItem() on the custom cell factory.
> >
> > A workaround is to wrap the setDisable() call in a Platform.runLater():
> >
> > `Platform.runLater(() -> { 
> >                 setDisable(true); 
> >             });`

Comment: Can you provide a public link to the bug report? The link you already provide request an authentication.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni AFAIK, there is no public link. You have to register (and it's free) to access it.